# Passing user-defined variables using MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, user-defined-types

How does one send variables of user defined types across processors using MPI ?

For predefined ones, I use

```
call mpi_recv(A,1,mpi_real8,root_process,mpi_any_tag,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
```

But what should be done for user defined types
For example for,

```
integer,parameter::type=selected_int_kind (16)  
integer(kind=type)::i
```

Please give your suggestions/comments.

Comment: This is not a user defined type, that is just one of the integer kinds.

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood. So, how do we pass those ? By what I meant is non-generic ones.